# Barometer App - Where to from here?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sensors, sensormanager

I am working on a basic barometer app and I have run into a slight snag.
I want to take the data that is being received and have it run through a text view that I have setup just for the pressure variable. Here is my code to this point:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Barometer extends Activity {
TextView baroText, timeText;
Button refresh;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.barometer_layout);
    uiVars();

    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PRESSURE);

    sensorManager.registerListener(new MyListener(), sensor,
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

public void uiVars(){
    baroText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pressureTxt);
    timeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeTxt);
    refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.baroRefreshBtn);
}

class MyListener implements SensorEventListener {
    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        long timestamp = event.timestamp;
        float value = event.values[0];
        // do something with the values
    }
}
}
```

I understand its likely something silly I am missing but I just wanted to get a second set of eyes looking at it. - Also if its any help I am running Android Studio as my IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    long timestamp = event.timestamp;
    float value = event.values[0];

    String valueString = String.valueOf(value);
    baroText.setText(valueString);
}
```

If what you want is display the value in this TextView.

Comment: Well all of that seems to work -- Just now AS kicked me back to an emulator over a physical device. Apparently its not registering my Nexus 7 Anymore. -- Gimme some time to check it out.